# Consecutive factor test

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

A positive number n is `consecutive-factored` if and only if it has factors, i and j where `i > 1, j > 1 and j = i +1`. I need a function that `returns 1` if its argument is consecutive-factored, otherwise it `returns 0`.For example, `24=2*3*4` and `3 = 2+1` so it has the function has to `return 1` in this case.

I have tried this:

```
public class ConsecutiveFactor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Scanner myscan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        int num = myscan.nextInt();
        int res = isConsecutiveFactored(num);
        System.out.println("Result: " + res);

    }
    static int isConsecutiveFactored(int number) {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
            int j = 0;
            int temp;
            temp = number %i;

            if (temp != 0) {
                continue;
            } 

            else {

                al.add(i);
                number = number / i;
                j++;

            }
        }


        System.out.println("Factors are: " + al);
        int LengthOfList = al.size();
        if (LengthOfList >= 2) {
            int a =al(0);
            int b = al(1);
            if ((a + 1) == b) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I'll start by saying that if such a pair of factors exists, then it's unique. This should point to their value.

Comment: Hint 2: you can use `Math.sqrt`, `Math.floor` and `Math.ceil` to your benefit.

Comment: @MukulGoel I have added the code that i tried but it is not working.

Comment: @SuneetaSingh : I would suggest you give a little harder try , this is the time you make your programming basics , try to resolve it yourself  ,this will help you think more logically

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid I am trying my best.

Comment: Why is my question being voted down?

Comment: I appreciate ypu trying. Hints : `j will be initialized to 0 with each iteration` , `dont you want to save temp if its not equalto 0?` , `are you just expecting 2 factors in your last segment of code`

Comment: @SuneetaSingh : yeah i know u r trying your best , i would suggest leave programming for a second , and concentrate completely on the logic , once you define the correct logic , your programming skills are good enough to make it .

Comment: @all : people I think we should only warn the new comers they dont know about the down vote thing , we should encourage them by warning not to do so again but not discourage by voting down simply

Comment: @all thank u for the support. I will try to improvise my logic to get the solution. As soon as i get my problem solved, I shall post my answer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check if its even, then try trial division

```
if(n%2!=0) return 0;
for(i=2;i<sqrt(n);++i) {
  int div=i*(i+1);
  if( n % div ==0) { return 1; }
}
return 0;
```

very inefficient, but fine for small numbers. Beyond that try a factorisation algorithm from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factorization.

Comment: Note only need to check upto k=sqrt(n) as k*(k+1) > n.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem with the above code. Following is the code.

```
public class ConsecutiveFactor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Scanner myscan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        int num = myscan.nextInt();
        int res = isConsecutiveFactored(num);
        System.out.println("Result: " + res);

    }
    static int isConsecutiveFactored(int number) {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
            int j = 0;
            int temp;
            temp = number % i;

            if (temp != 0) {
                continue;
            } 

            else {

                al.add(i);
                number = number / i;
                j++;

            }
        }

        Object ia[] = al.toArray();
        System.out.println("Factors are: " + al);
        int LengthOfList = al.size();
        if (LengthOfList >= 2) {
            int a = ((Integer) ia[0]).intValue();
            int b = ((Integer) ia[1]).intValue();

            if ((a + 1) == b) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: so you might have hated me for my previous comments , but see kiddo , you solved it yourself , now you are definitely a better programmer now and your approach are super awesome , carry on

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid thanx for the motivation. And I have not hated you for your comments for sure. ;)

Comment: What happens with 20? That has factors 2, 4, 5, 10, 20. By the definition at the top 4,5 are consecutive factors. However you algorithm returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same question and here is the answer I came up with.

```
public static int val(int a) {

    for(int i =2 ; i<=a/2;i++){
      if(a%i== 0){
        
        if(a%(i+1) == 0)return 1;  
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```